# Upload image to Graphql server using apollo kotlin

Tags: android, apollo-kotlin

I need to upload image to my Graphql server from android application. The details in the documentation is not working. I need an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with the solution. 1st I needed to create an upload scalar type. in Fragment class:

```
                requireContext().contentResolver.openFileDescriptor(
                    selectedImageUri!!,
                    "r",
                    null
                ) ?: return
                
                val file = File(
                    requireContext().cacheDir, requireContext().contentResolver.getFileName(
                        selectedImageUri
                    )
                )
                
                val body = UploadRequestBody(file, "image")
                
                val upload = DefaultUpload.Builder()
                    .content(file)
                    .fileName(file.name)
                    .contentType(body.contentType().toString())
                    .build()
```

In case what the UploadRequestBody class does:

```
class UploadRequestBody(
  private val file: File,
  private val contentType: String
) : RequestBody() {

override fun contentType() = "$contentType/*".toMediaTypeOrNull()

override fun contentLength() = file.length()

override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
    val length = file.length()
    val buffer = ByteArray(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE)
    val fileInputStream = FileInputStream(file)
    var uploaded = 0L
    fileInputStream.use { inputStream ->
        var read: Int
        while (inputStream.read(buffer).also { read = it } != -1) {
            uploaded += read
            sink.write(buffer, 0, read)
        }
    }
}
  companion object {
      private const val DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 2048
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you few questions??